# Какая cms лучше всего дружит с vue.js

Tags: вёрстка, vue.js

Подскажите пожалуйста, недавно начал осваивать vue и собственно зашел проект, который я хотел бы запилить на данном фреймвёрке. Руководство смущает момент на какую cms его лучше натянуть. Предложил сделать админку, но пока безрезультатно. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Любой, но без костылей будет не обойтись.

Comment: а можно поконкретнее и какие именно костыли, просто данный проект неплохо пригружен карусельками и я ссылаюсь, что вьюшка добавит скорости за счёт реактивность.

Comment: CMS вряд ли из коробки дружат с Vue. Из Фреймворков - Laravel с последних версий заточена под всё это.

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar спасибо, WP + WP Rest API + WP REST API Cache. попалось на глаза ещё такое сочетание, если можете прокомментировать - буду благодарен.

Comment: @IgorKushtym joomla rest api, modx rest api практически у всех современных cms последних версии есть rest api. Изучайте достоинства каждой cms и выбирайте.

Comment: @Alexander Semikashev, большое спасибо.

Comment: Пусть не по теме, но посмотри в сторону более низкоуровненного решения (в сравнении с CMS) решения на основе laravel. Он (php фреймворк laravel) дружит с vue из коробки (за счёт пакета laravel-mix).

Comment: @Максим К, ок, спасибо большое. просто ребята уже на умбраку засматриваются... =)